# Omnibox API: Is there a way to inline autocomplete from history?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

In my example I want to make extension for easy redirection for subreddits at reddit.com. [This](http://g.recordit.co/OBiXUIOm2r.gif) is what I have so far. However I would like to autocomplete from my history in omnibox, like those google search suggestions. For example if I type **te** to autocomplete **tech** inline and add suggestion underneath for **technology** and whatnot I have in my history that starts with "te". Is this even possible? If so can you point me in the right direction?

This is my very simple code so far

```
function navigate(url) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: url});
  });
}

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(
  function(text) {
  if(text.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
  if(text.indexOf('/r/') == 0) {
    navigate("https://www.reddit.com" + text); }
    else if(text.indexOf('r/') == 0) {
    navigate("https://www.reddit.com/" + text); }
    else 
    navigate("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + text); 
  }
  });
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [history API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history)?

Comment: Yeah but I was wondering about inline autocomplete in a Google Suggest manner

Comment: Well, what stops you from using [`setDefaultSuggestion`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox#method-setDefaultSuggestion)?

Comment: Because it shows text that is displayed in the first suggestion row underneath the URL bar. I want the suggestion to be inline

Comment: Ah, I finally got it. Your question would benefit from adding a screenshot.

Comment: I bolded that part in question, I think it should be much more clear now?